# How to create different Shortcuts for multiple instances with WIX?

Tags: wix, shortcut, multiple-instances

The Name property of the [Shortcut Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/shortcut.html) is not formattable. How can I create a shortcut with different Names for different instances in a multiple instances installer?